# If $a\sin A+b\cos A=c$, $b\sin B+a\cos B=d$, $a\tan A=b\tan B$, then $\frac1a+\frac1b=\frac1c+\frac1d$

Tags: trigonometry

$a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are four variables, and $A$ and $B$ are two angles.

$$\begin{align}
a \sin A + b \cos A &= c \tag1\\
b \sin B + a \cos B &= d \tag2\\
a \tan A &= b \tan B \tag3
\end{align}$$
To prove: $$\frac1a + \frac1b = \frac1c + \frac1d$$

I was thinking of maybe representing A and B as a part of a right-angled triangle, something like this.
[image: Right-angled Triangle]

I don't know how to integrate a, b c and d in this triangle though, as the question doesn't really mention about them in too much details.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Maybe you can add a drawing of a triangle (or more complicated geometric shape if needed) where $a, b, c$ and $d$ appear as sides and $A$ and $B$ as angles? That would make the question a bit easier to follow/visualize/interpret for all of us

Comment: hmm you could do that, but the question doesn't mention anything about geometric figures. I was thinking about something like a right-angled triangle, where A + B + 90 = 180 [Angle Sum], since trigonometrical ratios are mentioned. I don't really know how to implement a, b, c and d into the figure though.

Comment: @LeeTuah: What is the source of this question? Are you sure you've given it correctly? ... As stated, the four relations cannot hold simultaneously unless there are some extra constraints on the angles; having them be complementary angles in a right triangle isn't a particularly helpful constraint. (In that case, $\cos A=\sin B$ and $\sin B=\cos A$, which makes the left-hand sides of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ match, so that $c=d$, which is nice. But the final relation only holds for certain angles $A$.) Something seems wrong here.

Comment: You should edit the question to include missing information. As it stands, the statement you are trying to prove is not true for all $a,b,c,d,A$ and $B$. Counterexamples are not difficult to find.